# Create multiple partitions on kafka topic creation using pykafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka, pykafka

I am creating a kafka topic using pykafka python library api using the following code.

```
from pykafka import KafkaClient
client = KafkaClient(hosts="127.0.0.1:9092")
topic = client.topics[topic_name]
producer = topic.get_producer(sync=True)
producer.produce('message'))
```

Here the topic is created with only 1 partition as default.How can i assign more than one partition to the topic using pykafka something like

`topic.number_of_partitons=3` ?

Answer (score 0):

You're noticing pykafka's support for topic autocreation. When accessing a topic that doesn't already exist through the `client.topics` dict, the topic is automatically created with default settings defined in the broker configuration.

Pykafka also supports CLI integration with the topic creation and deletion APIs in Kafka 0.10.1. See the [source code](https://github.com/Parsely/pykafka/blob/7cf21a68b2a8848c632001a88e7ede0d959eea8b/pykafka/cli/kafka_tools.py#L265-L281) for information on how to use it. Here's an example:

```
python pykafka/cli/kafka_tools.py --broker_version 0.10.1 create_topic --num_partitions 3 --rpelication_factor 2 cli_testtopic
```